library not in scope in class
I have some code which I am trying to split into modules, the original code which compiles is:
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    LoRa.setPins(18, 23, 26);

}

and putting it in a class works as well in the main file, but splitting it into a header and implementation file always fails to build:
Compilation error: 'LoRa' was not declared in this scope
the code is as follows:
main.ino
#include "test.h"


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
  

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}


test.h
#ifndef LORA_H
#define LORA_H
#include <LoRa.h>


class test {

    public:
  
        test();
};

#endif


test.cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "test.h"


test::test() {

    LoRa.setPins(18, 23, 26);

}

I have rewrote this many times but it will just never build

Firstly, include what you use. You're explicitly using LoRa in test.cpp, so ithere should be #include <LoRa.h>. Depending on things being imported via an intermediate header (test.h) only makes life harder

Secondly, you added #ifndef LORA_H. Having include guards is good practice, but they MUST be unique, and usually they're based on the name of the file. Are you sure LoRa.h doesn't use exactly the same guard? If it does, it will appear empty when included ...

Dupe: Header guard same in different headers

Your test.h has the header guard for LoRa, and since your test.h gets included first, the LoRa.h file will be completely empty. (Since LORA_H was already defined, assuming it uses the LORA_H header guard).
Try using a different header guard define than LORA_H:
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <LoRa.h>


You're a genius, you have no idea how long it took me staring at that
